# Built in models with postgres

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop, loopback

I've migrated the builtin models (IE. User, Role, AccessToken) to a postgres database.

However, I get the following error when trying to request the API:

*error: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00*

I use the following code for the migration:

```
var appModels = ['User', 'Role', 'ACL', 'RoleMapping', 'AccessToken'];

    var ds = app.dataSources.talepen;
    ds.isActual(appModels, function(err, actual) {
      if (!actual) {
        ds.autoupdate(appModels, function(err) {
          if (err) throw (err);
        });
      } else {
        ds.automigrate(appModels, function(err) {
            if (err) throw (err);
        });
      }
    });
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

My bad, noticed I was sending an Authorization header with postman that was left over from another project.